# How do I redirect the asp.net page that contains a silverlight app from within the silverlight app?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf, silverlight

I have a multiview: view1 contains a button and view2 contains the silverlight app - basically a button.

Pressing the asp:button in view1 takes you to view2 and the silverlight app is activated.

How do I make the click of the button in the silverlight app take me back to view1.

I tried to use a WCF service with aspnetcompatibility enabled but that has not yielded results since httpcontext.current.response is null.

Maybe I should use an httphandler?

I was wondering if someone could guide me in the right direction.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a javascript method in the Silverlight hosting page and you can invoke the JS method using

```
HtmlPage.Window.Invoke("YourJSMethod", parameter);
```

In the ***YourJSMethod()*** javascript method you can write the logic to load the view 1 back.